# Rails - adding new record to all Models at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, models

Lets say I have a Model called  `Building` and another Model called `Issue`.

`Issue` `belongs_to` `Building`

`Building` `has_many` `Issues`

I have multiple `Buildings`, with many `Issues`.  Right now, I have to add each Issue to each Building one at a time.

How can I add one `Issue` to all `Buildings` at the same time?

Comment: Say you have all buildings have a same issue, x. If you change one x issue to y, do all buildings' issue change to y?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that would be the way it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you need a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship in both models. And create a table for that:

```
rails g migration create_buildings_issues building_id:integer issue_id:integer
```

Edit migration to remove auto index and add compound index:

```
create_table :buildings_issues, index: false do |t|
  t.references :building
  t.references :issue
end
add_index :buildings_issues, [:building_id, :issue_id]
```

Then create this table in DB:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then you could add issue to multiple buildings:

```
any_issue.buildings << Building.all
```

Or add issues to any building:

```
any_building.issues << heat_issue
```

Comment: This makes sense, I'm going to try it out.  One puzzle I'd like to add to this is: I'd like the ability to add single `Issues` to `Buildings` also. In other words, If I wanted to also just add "Heat" as an issue to "Building 3" but not all the other buildings, would I be able to do this with a has_and_belongs_to association?

Comment: is your `items` representing `issues`? or is that actually supposed to be `items`? I'm a bit confused where `items` come from

Comment: Thanks. The migration worked, but it now I can't figure out how to display the building name it's assocaited with. For instances, before I was showing the building by `@issue.building.name`. Now it gives me the error `undefined method "building" for #<Issue:0x007fc29cb28980>`. Any ideas?

Comment: right, you don't have `building` anymore, you have `buildings` since that issue is linked with many buildings.